# Angular - Get file from NgForm in TS, not from html

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to get the file of a input called Avatar in the ts file, without using the function directly from the html, I mean. Now I have it like this:

```
<input type="file" name="avatar" placeholder="Avatar" ngControl="avatar" ngModel (change)="file2Base64($event, 'avatar')">
```

but I'd like be able to erase the (change) function call as it is asyncronous and I need to call it inside another function, the one that sends the form, with the following line, using viewChild.

```
@ViewChild('frmRegister',{static:true}) registerform: NgForm;
```

```
this.file2Base64(this.registerform.value.avatar.target.files[0],"avatar");
```

However,it throws: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined, so I wonder how can I reference this form field in order to capture the file.

EDIT:

I have it like this now:

```
onRegister(form):void{
//code
this.file2Base64(form.value.avatar,"avatar");
```

It just returns "C:\fakepath\image.png", and if I try to use form.value.avatar.target.files[0], it returns a error as undefined.

Comment: The benefit of TypeScript is that you specify the type expected. Try changing your onRegister(form) to onRegister(form: NgForm). This will probably give you a better indication of the path to go down.

Comment: It keeps returning the path of the file. I dont know how to read the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form data to transfer the binary files. Using FormData,

```
 formData: FormData = new FormData();
 selectedFile: any;

 file2Base64(event){
    const file = event.target.files;
    if (file && file[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
       const imgSrc = reader.result;  
      };
      this.selectedFile = reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
     }
  }

    onRegister(form : NgForm):void{
      this.formData.append("avatar", this.selectedFile ? this.selectedFile : '');
 }
```